# How to retrieve the integer value of an enum?

Tags: c#

I have an enum

```
public enum Color
{
    Red = 0,
    Blue = 1,
    Yellow = 2
}
```

When I do this:

```
Color color = Color.Blue;
Console.Writeline(color.Value);
```

I want to see it's integer-value (1 in this case), but it outputs "Blue" instead.

How can I solve this?

I use .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can cast to int:

```
Console.Writeline((int)color.Value);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(Color.Blue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Enum.Parse(typeof(Color), "Blue", true);
```

Comment: The OP wants to get the integer value of a particular enum value, not convert some string into an enum value.